# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION on line 313

Tags: php, function

I'm getting this error.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION
I know that is because of my old php version, but I have to fix it to work on all php versions, because the client may have an old php version too.
the error on this line:

$pattern = '#(' . array_reduce( $pattern_array, function ( $carry, $item ) {

I tried playing around but it is not working.

My Php Code:

```
function theme_oembed_videos() {

    global $post;

    if ( $post && $post->post_content ) {

        global $shortcode_tags;
        // Make a copy of global shortcode tags - we'll temporarily overwrite it.
        $theme_shortcode_tags = $shortcode_tags;

        // The shortcodes we're interested in.
        $shortcode_tags = array(
            'video' => $theme_shortcode_tags['video'],
            'embed' => $theme_shortcode_tags['embed']
        );
        // Get the absurd shortcode regexp.
        $video_regex = '#' . get_shortcode_regex() . '#i';

        // Restore global shortcode tags.
        $shortcode_tags = $theme_shortcode_tags;

        $pattern_array = array( $video_regex );

        // Get the patterns from the embed object.
        if ( ! function_exists( '_wp_oembed_get_object' ) ) {
            include ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-oembed.php';
        }
        $oembed = _wp_oembed_get_object();
        $pattern_array = array_merge( $pattern_array, array_keys( $oembed->providers ) );

        // Or all the patterns together.
        $pattern = '#(' . array_reduce( $pattern_array, function ( $carry, $item ) {
            if ( strpos( $item, '#' ) === 0 ) {
                // Assuming '#...#i' regexps.
                $item = substr( $item, 1, -2 );
            } else {
                // Assuming glob patterns.
                $item = str_replace( '*', '(.+)', $item );
            }
            return $carry ? $carry . ')|('  . $item : $item;
        } ) . ')#is';

        // Simplistic parse of content line by line.
        $lines = explode( "\n", $post->post_content );
        foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
            $line = trim( $line );
            if ( preg_match( $pattern, $line, $matches ) ) {
                if ( strpos( $matches[0], '[' ) === 0 ) {
                    $ret = do_shortcode( $matches[0] );

                } else {
                   $ret = wp_oembed_get( $matches[0] );

                }
                return $ret;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to declare the function outside of array_reduce and then pass it like `array_reduce($pattern_array, "arrayReduceCallback")` ? How old is the php version? < 4?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a named function (like "`myfunction`" but with a better name).
`array_reduce()` takes a string as the second parameter, which is the name of the function.

```
function myfunction($carry, $item) {
    if ( strpos( $item, '#' ) === 0 ) {
        // Assuming '#...#i' regexps.
        $item = substr( $item, 1, -2 );
    } else {
        // Assuming glob patterns.
        $item = str_replace( '*', '(.+)', $item );
    }
        return $carry ? $carry . ')|('  . $item : $item;
};

...

$pattern = '#(' . array_reduce( $pattern_array, "myfunction" ) . ')#is';
```

Comment: I did your code after renaming myfunction to all_patterns but I'm getting this error:  Warning: array_reduce() [function.array-reduce]: The second argument, 'all_patterns', should be a valid callback in  C:\AppServ\www\the-path\functions.php on line 313

Comment: does `array_reduce` have access to `all_patterns`? Like, are they in different and unconnected php files, or in different scopes? Maybe `array_reduce` thinks `all_patterns` doesn't actually exist...